# Uncertain Future of WebView and Lack of Enclosing ScrollView in wkWebView For MacOS

Tags: macos, wkwebview, nsscrollview

wkWebView for MacOS does not expose it's enclosing scrollView.  My application fundamentally depends of WebView's scrollview.  I would like to conform to Apple's recommendation by switching from WebView to wkWebView, but without scrollview I can't.  (Actually I just need scrollView's contentView and documentView.)

I fear Apple will disable WebView in the future and ruin years of work. Do I have any options?

Comment: I have a similar issue. I need the scrollview content size before and after view resizing and magnification. I will look into it. Going down the subviews also doesn't give a NSScrolView. Currently the only thing would be to use javascript to scroll or to embed the WKWebView in a NSScrollView and then sync them. I don't know which solution is worse since we have the enclosingScrollView which is always nil...

Comment: If you find out anything, please post it. thanks

Comment: I'm interested too. please do tag me too if you ever report back.

Comment: I have submitted a bug report: 42816307 ScrollView is missing from wkWebView

Comment: After conferring with Apple, I have learned that webView is being completely re-written for macOS 10.15.  Presumably, that will solve the problem.  Using webView should be OK until then.  I will compile using 10.9.

Comment: @CarlCarlson do you mean ~WKWebView~ is being rewritten for 10.15? Any confirmation of that now that's it's about to be released?

Comment: Yes, WKWebView/webView.  I don't know which name they will use.  I have no new information since my post.  I have asked Apple  for an update on when it will be released, but received no response.

Comment: As of macOS 10.15 and Xcode 11.1  NSScrollView is not available according to Xcode 11.1  documentation running in macOS 10.15.

Comment: Got an answer from Apple forums today:  No. Legacy webviews are not a problem at this time. WkWebView still cannot even print on the Mac.
 
However, I would encourage you to resolve this problem sooner rather than later. Most anything you need can be implemented in HTML and JavaScript.